# color and rendering Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, color

[image]I have finished my scene but the colors for my objects are not changing. they are still the default color greyish. I finished creating the scene before making color changes, is there a certain order I should follow to change colors?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add some images that show your problem. Without that it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: where would I upload an image too?

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of the shader editor]

before you hit the render button, click the material property icon down the right corner, click on new material, you could check the render in view port while assigning materials to your mesh. i hope this helps

Comment: Have tried using the "nodes" and that does not work either.